# Do we always have to allocate a @property with the retain attribute?

Tags: objective-c, retain

I learned that if a `@property` has the attribute `retain` it should always be released in the `dealloc` method. But if the program never allocates memory for the property this means we release an unallocated object, right? Does this mean that the property *must* be allocated in the `init` method?

Comment: I am currently using it without ARC, for learning purposes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But if the program never allocates memory for the property this means we release an unallocated object, right?

Wrong. If you say `[self->myVar release]` in `dealloc`, then either `myVar` has been assigned a value or it has not:

- If it has, it is now released, which is what you want.
- If it has not, it is `nil`, and nothing happens and no harm done, because a message to `nil` does nothing.